# can pdf file be generated from data in db in yii

Tags: pdf, yii

CAN ANYONE ONEguide me. i dont know how do i move on .the thing is I have description ,image as fields of table1 userA logins as soon as ,userA creates this record with decitpion and image field i want to generate a pdf file with image and decription as well provide a download link for the userB when logins to download the pdf file.

i need to know can pdf file be generated from data in db am using yii

my questions are as follows

is it possible?
if not what better can be suggested?
if possible is their any extension.
can anyone provide some guidance.

Please let me know i am doing this for the first time but not sure of how to carry on

Answer (score 1):

It is possible yes. I do not use an extension I use a library called HTML2PDF
http://www.html2pdf.fr/en
I put it in my extensions folder. 
I created a pdf action that has this code

```
<?php

class Pdf extends CAction {

    public function run() {
        $controller = $this->getController();

        \Yii::import('core.extensions.Html2Pdf.HTML2PDF');
        //use the existing filters

        $model_name = $controller->modelName();
        $model = new $model_name('search');
        $dataProvider = $model->active()->search();
        //remove the pagination
        $dataProvider->setPagination(false);

        //get the html to transform
        $content = $controller->renderPartial('pdf',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'title'=>$controller->modelName() . ' - '.date('F j, Y, G:i'),
        ), true);
        try
        {
            if(isset($_GET['test'])) {
                echo $content;
            } else {
                //create the PDF
                $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
                $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
                $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
                $html2pdf->Output($controller->modelName() . '_'.date('Y-m-d').'.pdf');
            }
        }
        catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

That I can attach to any controller like this

```
/**
 * @return array actions to be mapped to this controller
 */
public function actions(){
   return array(
        'csv'=>array(
          'class'=>'core.components.actions.Csv',
          'field_list'=>array('t.id', 't.name', 't.status'),
        ),
        'pdf'=>array(
          'class'=>'core.components.actions.Pdf',
        ),
    );
}
```

. There is a view called pdf that has what I want to export as PDF. I am actually creating simple HTML (so nothing very complicated and most of the styles are inline). An example is

```
<page backtop="22mm" backbottom="8mm" backleft="0" backright="0">
    <page_header>
        <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $title?></h1>
        <table backleft="10mm" style="width: 700px;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">ID</td>
                <td style="width: 75%; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Name</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Status</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </page_header>
    <page_footer>
        <table style="width: 700px; border-top: 1px solid black;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 50%"></td>
                <td style="text-align: right; width: 50%">page [[page_cu]]/[[page_nb]]</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </page_footer>    
    <table style="width: 700px;" align="center">

<?php 
    foreach($dataProvider->getData() as $record) {
?>      <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%;"><?php echo $record->id?></td>
            <td style="width: 75%;"><?php echo $record->name?></td>
            <td style="width: 15%;"><?php echo ucfirst($record->status)?></td>
        </tr>

<?php 
    }
?>  </table>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks:) mihai for the quick response i have a question i.e., how do i provide a download link to download it this pdf ,here where is the pdf stored , my need is when record is generated as pdf of record i.e., description and img to store in folder and a reference to the pdf file in folderi.e., unique file name to be provided for each record or what better can you suggest me

Comment: This line `$html2pdf->Output($controller->modelName() . '_'.date('Y-m-d').'.pdf');` allows you to download the file right there and there. Change it to something like 
`$html2pdf->Output('directory/file_xxxx.pdf', 'F');` to save it on the server. To create a unique name you can create a hash string in php and just use that as its name. Save it in a download friendly location and give it to the user when you need it.

Comment: your code is much worthy then other extensions i have look up for. i have placed the pdf class in model folder and placed the function actions() in one of my controller(A) and pdf view i have placed in view(A)of controller (A). I know  am going wrong.i get an error here as  core.components.actions.Pdf point it to existing directory.i think i am placing the code at wrong places can you please guide me

Comment: do not just copy paste my code, change and adapt it to your needs. I have another application structure compared to the normal yii because it suits my needs better. Probably you do not have this core.components.actions.Pdf, just change it to your folder structure.

Comment: so shall i place it in projects components folder will that work out

Comment: so shall i place it in projects components folder will that work out Yii::import('core.extensions.Html2Pdf.HTML2PDF');.i want to ask you function action can be in any controller ?and the view to be in that controller?

Comment: If you place it there then you should probably use Yii::import('components.extensions.Html2Pdf.HTML2PDF'); or Yii::import('components.Html2Pdf.HTML2PDF');